# Permissions problem in programming a discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this line of code

```js
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('**:x: You Don't Have Permission **')
```

When someone comes with someone who does not have a Permission and uses the bot command to not reply to him or do anything, I want him to reply to him and say **You Don't Have Permission**

---

And when someone comes with a Permission and uses the command, it works and responds normally

================

> Note: He checks the person if he has a Permission. He activates the code if he does not have a Permission. He does not reply or do anything in the shortcut. I want him to reply to it. **You Don't Have Permission**

===============================

> Note 2 : i'm using **Commandhandler**

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question correctly, all you need to change is the statement to:

```
message.reply("YOU DON'T HAVE PERMISSION")
```

the if looks fine, as it shown here:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#creating-a-role-with-permissions